# bugzilla template choose-product

Tags: javascript, html, templates, bugzilla

I want to get the choose page, for (New and Browse), to show drop down boxes for classification, product, component and cf_subcomponent.
and populate with valid select options based on the selection of the previous field.

I do not thing I am getting the variables correct for bugzilla, and also think my JS is not correct.

i want to end up with this in the URI for the next page-

```
http://bugs/buglist.cgi?product=<product1>&component=<component1>&cf_subcomponent=<subcomponent1>
```

Heres what I have so far

```
[%# INTERFACE:
  # classifications: array of hashes, with an 'object' key representing a
  #                  classification object and 'products' the list of
  #                  product objects the user can enter bugs into.
  # target:   the script that displays this template.
  # cloned_bug_id: ID of the bug being cloned.
  # format:   the desired format to display the target.
  #%]

[% IF target == "enter_bug.cgi" %]
  [% title = "Enter $terms.Bug" %]
  [% h2 = BLOCK %]First, you must pick a product on which to enter [% terms.abug %]: [% END %]
[% ELSIF target == "describecomponents.cgi" %]
  [% title = "Browse" %]
  [% h2 = "Select a product category to browse:" %]
[% END %]

[% DEFAULT title = "Choose a Product" %]
[% PROCESS global/header.html.tmpl %]

[%# This script displays the descriptions for selected components. %]

var products = new Array([% classification.products.size %]);
var components = new Array([% product.components.size %]);
var comp_desc = new Array([% product.components.size %]);
var flags = new Array([% product.components.size %]);
[% count = 0 %]
[% FOREACH product = classification.products %]
    products[[% count %]] = "[% product.name FILTER js %]";
    [%- FOREACH c = product.components %]
        [% NEXT IF NOT c.is_active %]
        components[[% count %]] = "[% c.name FILTER js %]";
        comp_desc[[% count %]] = "[% c.description FILTER html_light FILTER js %]";
        [% flag_list = [] %]
        [% FOREACH f = c.flag_types.bug %]
          [% NEXT UNLESS f.is_active %]
          [% flag_list.push(f.id) %]
        [% END %]
        [% FOREACH f = c.flag_types.attachment %]
          [% NEXT UNLESS f.is_active %]
          [% flag_list.push(f.id) %]
        [% END %]
        flags[[% count %]] = [[% flag_list.join(",") FILTER js %]];

        [% count = count + 1 %]
    [%- END %]
[% END %]

function set_assign_to() {
    // Based on the selected component, fill the "Assign To:" field
    // with the default component owner, and the "QA Contact:" field
    // with the default QA Contact. It also selectively enables flags.
    var form = document.Create;

    var index = -1;
    if (form.component.type == 'select-one') {
        index = form.component.selectedIndex;
    } else if (form.component.type == 'hidden') {
        // Assume there is only one component in the list
        index = 0;
    }
    if (index != -1) {
        var component = components[index];

        document.getElementById('comp_desc').innerHTML = comp_desc[index];

        // We show or hide the available flags depending on the selected component.
        var flag_rows = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('bz_flag_type', 'tbody');
        for (var i = 0; i  1 ? 1 : 0;
            var show = 0;
            // Loop through the allowed flag ids for the selected component
            // and if we match, then show the row, otherwise hide the row.
            for (var j = 0; j 


    


  [%# We can't use the select block in these two cases for various reasons. %]
  
    [% classification_desc_url = BLOCK -%]
      describecomponents.cgi?
    [% END %]
    [% INCLUDE "bug/field-label.html.tmpl"
      field = bug_fields.classification editable = 1
      desc_url =classification_desc_url
    %]      
    
      
        [%- FOREACH class = classifications %]
          [% NEXT IF NOT class.is_active %]
          
            [% class.name FILTER html -%]
          
        [%- END %]
      

      
       
       
    

    
      [%# Enclose the fieldset in a nested table so that its width changes based
        # on the length on the classification description. %]
      
        
          
            
              Classification Description
              Select a classification to read its description.
            
          
        
      
    
  

  [%# We can't use the select block in these two cases for various reasons. %]
  
    [% product_desc_url = BLOCK -%]
      describecomponents.cgi?classification=[% classification.name FILTER uri %]
    [% END %]
    [% INCLUDE "bug/field-label.html.tmpl"
      field = bug_fields.product editable = 1
      desc_url = product_desc_url
    %]      
    
      
        [%- FOREACH p = classification.products %]
          [% NEXT IF NOT p.is_active %]
          
            [% p.name FILTER html -%]
          

        [%- END %]
      

      
       
       
    

    
      [%# Enclose the fieldset in a nested table so that its width changes based
        # on the length on the product description. %]
      
        
          
            
              Product Description
              Select a product to read its description.
            
          
        
      
    
  

  [%# We can't use the select block in these two cases for various reasons. %]
  
    [% component_desc_url = BLOCK -%]
      describecomponents.cgi?product=[% product.name FILTER uri %]
    [% END %]
    [% INCLUDE "bug/field-label.html.tmpl"
      field = bug_fields.component editable = 1
      desc_url = component_desc_url
    %]      
    
      
        [%# Build the lists of assignees and QA contacts if "usemenuforusers" is enabled. %]
        [%- FOREACH c = product.components %]
          [% NEXT IF NOT c.is_active %]
          
            [% c.name FILTER html -%]
          

        [%- END %]
      

      
       
       
    

    
      [%# Enclose the fieldset in a nested table so that its width changes based
        # on the length on the component description. %]
      
        
          
            
              Component Description
              Select a component to read its description.
            
          
        
      
    
  

  
  [% USE Bugzilla %]

  [% FOREACH field = Bugzilla.active_custom_fields %]
    [% IF field.name == "cf_subcomponent" %]
        [% NEXT UNLESS field.enter_bug %]
        [% SET value = ${field.name}.defined ? ${field.name} : "" %]
        
            [% INCLUDE bug/field.html.tmpl 
                bug = default, field = field, value = value, editable = 1, 
                value_span = 3 %]
        
    [% END %]
  [% END %]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a full JavaScript for each selection, long winded but i could not find another way.

As you may see this is an example, i had other components up the tree, but this should tell you how to do it.

```
[%# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
  # License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
  # file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
  #
  # This Source Code Form is "Incompatible With Secondary Licenses", as
  # defined by the Mozilla Public License, v. 2.0.
  #%]

[%# INTERFACE:
  # classifications: array of hashes, with an 'object' key representing a
  #                  classification object and 'products' the list of
  #                  product objects the user can enter bugs into.
  # target:   the script that displays this template.
  # cloned_bug_id: ID of the bug being cloned.
  # format:   the desired format to display the target.
  #%]

[% IF target == "enter_bug.cgi" %]
  [% title = "Enter $terms.Bug" %]
  [% h2 = BLOCK %]First, you must pick a product on which to enter [% terms.abug %]: [%     END %]
[% ELSIF target == "describecomponents.cgi" %]
    [% target = "buglist.cgi" %]
  [% title = "Browse" %]
    [% h2 = "Select a product category to browse:" %]
[% END %]

[% DEFAULT title = "Choose a Product" %]
[% PROCESS global/header.html.tmpl %]

[% USE Bugzilla %]
[%# This script displays the descriptions for selected components. %]
<script type="text/javascript">
var classifications = new Array([% classifications.size %]);
[% count = 0 %]
[% FOREACH cl = classifications %]
    classifications[[% count %]] = "[% cl.object.name FILTER js %]";
[% count = count + 1 %]
[% END %]

function setComponentSelection() {
//hide all following areas
document.getElementById("subCompBody").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('subcomponent').selectedIndex=-1;

var compSel = document.getElementById('component');
var compInd = compSel.selectedIndex;
if(compInd != -1)
{
    var subcompSel = document.getElementById('subcomponent');
    subcompSel.options.length = 0;

    //get classification
    var classSel = document.getElementById('classification');
    var classInd = classSel.selectedIndex;
    var showSubCompBody = 0;
    if(classInd != -1)
    {
        [% FOREACH cll = classifications %]
            if(classSel.options[classInd].text == "[% cll.object.name FILTER js %]")
            {
                [% bug.classification = cll %]
                var prodSel = document.getElementById('product');
                var prodInd = prodSel.selectedIndex;
                if(prodInd!=-1)
                {
                    [% FOREACH p = cll.products %]
                        if(prodSel.options[prodInd].text == "[% p.name FILTER js %]")
                        {
                            [% bug.product = p %]
                            [% FOREACH c = p.components %]
                                if(compSel.options[compInd].text == "[% c.name FILTER js %]")
                                {
                                    [% bug.component = c %]
                                    [% FOREACH field = Bugzilla.active_custom_fields %]
                                        [% IF field.name == "cf_subcomponent" %]
                                            [%- FOREACH fl = field.legal_values %]
                                                [% IF c.name == fl.visibility_value.name %]
                                                    showSubCompBody = 1;
                                                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                                                    option.text = "[% fl.name FILTER js %]";
                                                    option.value = "[% fl.name FILTER js %]";
                                                    subcompSel.add(option);
                                                [% END %]
                                            [% END %]
                                        [% END %]
                                    [% END %]
                                }
                            [% END %]       
                        }
                    [% END %]
                }
            }
        [% END %]
    }

    if(showSubCompBody==1)
        document.getElementById("subCompBody").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
}

function hideCombos(){
//hide all combo boxes if java script is supported, if not they should all stay shown
document.getElementById("productBody").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("componentBody").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("subCompBody").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>

<h2>[% h2 FILTER html %]</h2>
<form action="[% target %]?component=[% c.name FILTER uri %]&cf_subcomponent=[%     subComp.name FILTER uri %]
          [%- IF cloned_bug_id %]&amp;cloned_bug_id=[% cloned_bug_id FILTER uri %][% END -%] 
          [%- IF format %]&amp;format=[% format FILTER uri %][% END %]">
<table>
<tbody id="componentBody">
  <tr id="field_container_component">
[% component_desc_url = BLOCK -%]
  describecomponents.cgi?
[% END %]
[% INCLUDE "bug/field-label.html.tmpl"
  field = bug_fields.component editable = 1
  desc_url = component_desc_url
%]      
<td>
  <select name="component" id="component" onchange="setComponentSelection();"
          size="10" aria-required="true" class="required">
    [%- FOREACH cl = classifications %]
        [%- FOREACH p = cl.products %]
            [%- FOREACH c = p.components %]
                <option value="[% c.name FILTER html %]"
                    id="v[% c.id FILTER html %]_product">
                    [% c.name FILTER html -%]
                </option>
            [% END %]
        [% END %]
    [%- END %]
  </select>
</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<tbody id="subCompBody">
<tr>
    <td>
        <font color="red">*</font>Sub Component:      
    </td>
    <td>
        [% FOREACH field = Bugzilla.active_custom_fields %]
            [% IF field.name == "cf_subcomponent" %]
                <select name="cf_subcomponent" id="subcomponent" "
                    size="10" aria-required="true" class="required">
                    [% FOREACH fl = field.legal_values %]
                        <option value="[% fl.name FILTER html %]"
                            id="v[% fl.id FILTER html %]_product">
                            [% fl.name FILTER html -%]
                        </option>
                    [% END %]
                </select>
            [% END %]
        [% END %]
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="submit" value="Select"/>
    </th>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
hideCombos();
</script>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```